# Handle connect callbacks are not working in Tapjoy unity android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, tapjoy

I have used `Tapjoy` to show offer wall in my game. It works fine in the sample app given by the `Tapjoy` plugin for unity. I have provided my Android SDK key. But it does not work in my game. I found that `Tapjoy.IsConnected` shows true, but either `HandleConnectSuccess` or `HandleConnectFailure` callbacks were not called. I have even checked the internet connectivity. Please help.